# Django using "." as primary key gives 404

Tags: python, django

I am using DRF along with drf-nested-routers to configure my routing. I have an api route structure this way.

`/posts/1/comments`

Now instead of using the id I have decided to use the name of the object instead.

`/posts/mypost/comments`

This works perfectly but an issue occurs when a `.` is being added to the key.

`/posts/my.post/comments`

When including a `.` as part of the key for the resource, it returns a `404` error on Django. I have been trying to debug this issue to no avail.

Comment: Well depending on your `path`, a dot is not valid. Can you share the related `path`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is you are **not allowing dot `.`** in your url pattern.

You can just add the characters you want to accept as part of your url inside the square brackets:

```
url(r'^posts/(?P<post_name>[-\w.]+)/comments/$', views.your_view)
```

The above include `.` and `-` along with all word characters(alphanumeric and underscore).

Comment: @Edwin, let me know if this helped.